# can datetime type of sql server hold time only?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, database

I'm trying to store time in format

> 05:00 PM

in database. but when i insert the data it automatically stores date as well like

> 2016-07-20 17:00:00.000

All i want only

> 17:00

in database

Comment: why don't use use `time` data type ?

Comment: Use the `time` data type instead, if it's available (SQL Server 2008 or later). You still won't control the *format*, because such a notion doesn't exist. These data types are internally just *numbers*, that store e.g. the number of 100 nanosecond intervals that have occurred since some fixed start point in time.

Comment: Just a note, time data type will store only up to 23:59, if you're thinking about storing duration, it might not be the best solution.

Comment: "i want only 17:00 in database". This sounds like a bad requirement. The database stores the data. Something else should be concerned about the presentation aspect.

Comment: @JamesZ - what makes you think they're trying to store duration? There example input is `05:00 PM` and I don't know of anyone who would describe a duration thus.

Comment: @Squirrel i have tried using time but when insert `05:00 PM` it returns an error `invalid value for cell`

Comment: no issue .... `declare @t time;
select @t = '05:00 PM'
select @t`

Comment: @user2992655 - try entering it as `17:00` rather than `05:00 PM`. Again, if you're using these data types, they don't *have* a format. Don't confuse *data* with a particular representation. Also, try to get out of the habit of using the grid presented by `Edit Top 200 rows` function to insert data - it's rather nasty.

Comment: @Squirrel Can i convert `'05:00 PM'` to `'17:00'` in C#.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i need it entering `05:00 PM` format and I'm inserting from a webform with FormView Control.

Comment: Sql server has a Time data type since 2008 version, but the .Net framework doesn't have a time data type, only datetime. Therefor, you might want to check [Noda time](http://nodatime.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant store Time  only in a datetime field it stores default date,Use TIME data type if you are on 2008..

```
declare @t datetime
select @t=cast(getdate() as time)
print @t
---Jan  1 1900  9:17AM

declare @t time
select @t=cast(getdate() as time)
print @t
---09:17:48.3330000
```

for sql 2008

```
select cast(getdate() as time)
--09:17:25.4400000
```

for 2005

```
select convert(varchar(10),getdate(),108)
---09:17:33
```

your exact format

```
select cast(datepart(hour,getdate()) as varchar(10))+':'+ cast(datepart(minute,getdate()) as varchar(10))
---9:17
```

You also can use FORMAT to store only time (From SQl 2012)

```
select FORMAT(GETDATE(),'HH:MM')
--09:07
```

Comment: Thanks! worked like a charm (y). I'm using sql server 2014.

Answer (score 1):

First, as suggested in the comments, you should use [time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb677243.aspx) type instead of `datetime`.

The format of `time` in SQL Server is : `hh:mm:ss` or `hh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn`. If you want time to be in `AM` `PM` format just use this :

```
CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST('17:00:00.000' AS TIME),100)
```